# chat.stackexchange smartphone and desktop application request

Tags: feature-request

The various rooms in chat.stackexchange are really informative even for a noob like me. It allows you to ask for clarification without fear of downvote or closure.
Just today some experienced user was talking about being unable to access the chat because the newer version of chrome won't support or something. I didn't grasp it completely.
My request is: what if we  have an application that allows quick access to these rooms from either your desktop or from your smart phone??
What i have in my head is this: The application would ask you to login using the regular options available, say Yahoo. It'll then list all the available rooms. You can join whichever you want and viola you're chatting with your experienced mates.
The GUI should be similar to the one on the website.
I guess it'll be productive for experienced users. Inputs on this please

Comment: There's no API for the chat at the moment, so this won't be possible unless you just wrap a web view.

Comment: I have no problem with chat in Chrome 22.0.1229.94 m which is up to date.

Comment: You guys are for or against this idea? :)

Comment: @FasihKhatib I'm for a better integration of the SE Site with Mobile platforms.  In fact I'm currently [working on an app](http://apptivate.ms/apps/28/metrose) to do this.  The limiting factor for now, is the [API calls](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs).  SE hasn't opened anything for the chat, and I don't foresee them doing this anytime soon.